# AzureML: Automatically update deployment when new version of model is available

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an AzureML pipeline that trains and registers a model regularly. Each run creates a new version of the registered model. My goal is to re-deploy the model whenever there is a new version available.

In another script I deploy the registered model and overwrite any existing deployments:

```
service = Model.deploy(
    workspace=ws,
    name=service_name,
    models=[model],
    inference_config=inference_config,
    deployment_config=deployment_config,
    deployment_target=compute_target,
    overwrite=True
)
```

Initially, I thought it would make sense to include the deployment in the pipeline, but I cannot figure out how to refer to the workspace within the pipeline step.

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a pipeline step, you can access the `Workspace` via:

```
run = Run.get_context()
ws = run.experiment.workspace
```

Comment: Getting access to the workspace worked well, but I can not create compute target objects within the pipeline to initiate the service on. Apparently this is a known issue: [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20351)